# Number of Word Counts in a Sentence - C program

Tags: c, string

I am thinking of a C program which will take a sentence as an input and display the words in it with number of occurances. e.g.

```
Input = I love you and I hate you
Output = I 2 love 1 you 2 and 1 hate 1
```

Can you suggest me the logic or code for this program? I have in below program seprated the words from a sentence.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
        char str[] = "I love you and I hate you";
        char delims[] = " ";
        int i =0;
        char *result = NULL;
        result = strtok (str, delims);
        while(result !=NULL)
        {
                ++i;
                printf("%s\n",result);
                result = strtok (NULL, delims);
        }
}
```

Now How can I store these words with their number of occurances in the sentence.

Comment: Seems like a home assignment

Comment: @rounak Do not people help out here for the programming problems ?

Answer (score 3):

Store words in a collection of some kind, together with a counter. For every word see if it already exists in your collection, and if it does then increase the counter.